# Eclipse PyDev Support Message needs Removal

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, adt, pydev

I am getting this message everytime I use eclipse to open .py file. If click on the CloseButton OR ShowLaterButton OR ReadItButton, the eclipse automatically closes. I am unable to fix this.

[image]

My Eclipse Version : PyDev to Android ADT, Eclipse. Checked for updates, and its on the latest version.

OS Platform : Windows 8

I am not able to get any help on google search for this. I have been using Eclipse+PyDev for about 1 year now, and I have never had problems till today.

How can I make this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad design by pydev folks.

To make this pop-up go away, you have to click on the hyperlink in the text section & then click read-it.

I am disappointed that opensource community has done such a thing. I have lost 3hours trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it... you mean you click on show later or read it and it closes Eclipse? That should definitely not happen (I'll take a look at that as this is definitely not what it was supposed to do -- although I can't really reproduce this here).

Comment: Also, which Eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Humm, I took a look at the code and I think I found the issue (https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/b56423e2ac8667572627bf1042d868c6310be3aa) -- the fix will be available in PyDev 3.8 (as it's a critical I'll try to release it tomorrow).

Comment: Hey Fabio - thanks a lot for your reply. You are doing a great job fixing this.

Comment: just to add to this more clearly, if you donot click on the hyperlink inside the text box - this pop-up does NOT go - and it does not allow me to use eclipse.